# Share something other than text or image in Codenameone with ShareButton in iOS

Tags: java, codenameone

I am trying to allow a user to share a csv file in the same way that you could share an image - sharebutton.setImageToShare(fileName, mimeType) - with the ShareButton in Codenameone. However there doesn't seem to be an option for something other than plain text or an image.

I tried using setImageToShare with my csv file and the csv mimetype, but it doesn't work (I assume iOS is doing a check to verify it's an image). I can create a Message and set the mimetype to CSV, but that restricts me from doing anything but sharing by email.

In Android the Message function uses the same mechanism as share, so this is only an issue for me with iOS.

Comment: I guess this is something we can improve in the iOS share API to make it more generic. The original use case of the API assumed image and that's what we tested on. You can file an RFE on that